# Hide A Href link with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML

```
<li class="navUser-item navUser-item--account">
     <a class="navUser-action" href="/login.php">Login</a> 
     <span class="navUser-or">or</span> // Hide this
     <a class="navUser-action" href="/login.php?action=create_account">Sign Up</a>  // Hide this
</li>
```

I'm trying to hide the last ahref and the span tag using Javascript.  I can't seem to get this to work as expected, I have tried the following:

I was hoping I could extend this to look for a given Href and if its of such value i.e create account then hide it however no such luck.

```
var litag = document.getElementsByClassName('navUser-item navUser-item--account'), i;

for (i = 0; i < litag.length; i += 1) {

   litag[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

I then tried the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('navUser-item navUser-item--account a:nth-last-child(2)')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

tried finding the second a and yet didn't work, can someone shed some light into how I go about hiding the span and the last a href?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `querySelector` like this

```
var link = document.querySelector('a[href="/login.php?action=create_account"]');

link.style.display = 'none';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mtinra/nsznwbgk/

Edit: or use `querySelectorAll` to select both span and a

```
var myEl = document.querySelectorAll('.navUser-item > span, a[href="/login.php?action=create_account"]');

for (var el of myEl){
    el.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: That worked thanks, do you know how I would remove the span tag too ?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have only one navigation menu (I'm choosing the first element with class name `navUser-item` here `var childnodes = mainNav[0].childNodes;`) you could do something like this:

```js
var mainNav = document.getElementsByClassName('navUser-item');
var childnodes = mainNav[0].childNodes;

for (i = 0; i < childnodes.length; i += 1) {
  if (childnodes[i].className && childnodes[i].className.match('navUser-action')) {
    if (childnodes[i].href && childnodes[i].href.indexOf('create_account') !== -1) {
      childnodes[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  } else if (childnodes[i].className && childnodes[i].className.match('navUser-or')) {
    childnodes[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="navUser-item navUser-item--account">
  <a class="navUser-action" href="/login.php">Login</a>
  <span class="navUser-or">or</span>
  <a class="navUser-action" href="/login.php?action=create_account">Sign Up</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally find it better to change classes and use CSS for toggling display of items.

```js
var links = document.getElementById('link-list').children;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].className.match(/(?:^|\s)navUser-register(?!\S)/)) {
    console.log(links[i]);
    links[i].className = links[i].className.match(/show/) ?
      links[i].className.replace(/show/, 'hide') :
      links[i].className.replace(/hide/, 'show');
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<li id="link-list" class="navUser-item navUser-item--account">
  <a class="navUser-action" href="/login.php">Login</a> 
  <span class="navUser-or navUser-register show">or</span>
  <a class="navUser-action navUser-register show" href="/login.php?action=create_account">Sign Up</a>
</li>
```

**EDIT:** You could also surround desired elements in a div tag and set it's display property depending on the current page. In my opinion this would be the easiest way.
`<div id="register-page" class="show"> ... elements ... </div>`
And your JavaScript part would include just a search for element by this ID and toggling it's class from show to hide.
`var div = document.getElementById('register-page')
div.className.match(/show/) ? div.className.replace(/show/, 'hide') : div.replace(/hide/, 'show');`